# Vb.net How to set correct point or location of the screen for screen shot

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to screen capture in my application please refer with the picture below that has red mark

[image]

but it only captures this part

[image]

here is the code by the way

```
Private Function TakeScreenShot(ByVal Control As Control) As Bitmap

    Dim screenSize As Size = New Size(Control.Width, Control.Height)

    Dim screenGrab As New Bitmap(Control.Width, Control.Height)

    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenGrab)

    g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Control.Location.X, Control.Location.Y), Point.Empty, screenSize)

    Return screenGrab

End Function
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```vb
g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Control.Location.X, Control.Location.Y), Point.Empty, screenSize)
```

should be this:

```vb
g.CopyFromScreen(Control.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, screenSize)
```

`PointToScreen` will convert between the control's coordinate system and screen coordinates. `Point.Empty` is the origin in any control's coordinate system. This:

```vb
Control.PointToScreen(Point.Empty)
```

is equivalent to this:

```vb
Control.Parent.PointToScreen(Control.Location)
```

Comment: Very on point, thank you very much. this solves my problem.

Comment: If he hadn't been on point he'd be Oblio.